# Counting sectors in the complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let

$f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$,

$f(k)=\alpha\left(k+\frac{\beta}{n\alpha}\right)^{n}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C}$, $\alpha\neq0$, and $\text{Re}\, f(k)\geq0$ when $k\in\mathbb{R}$.

I note that $\{k\in\mathbb{C}:\text{Re}\,f(k)<0\}\cap\mathbb{R}=\emptyset$. Also i see that $D=\{k\in\mathbb{C}:\text{Re}\,f(k)<0\}$ consists of $n$ sectors.

How do i determine the number of sectors of $D$ in the upper half plane $\mathbb{C}^{+}=\{k\in\mathbb{C}:\text{Im}\,k>0\}$ and the lower half plane $\mathbb{C}^{-}=\{k\in\mathbb{C}:\text{Im}\,k<0\}$?

Comment: Well, how did you "see" that that set consists of sectors in the first place?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I looked at the $2n$ lines defined by $\text{Re}\, f(k)=0$. They originate from $-\frac{\beta}{n\alpha}$ and tend to infinity. They trace out $2n$ sectors. I guess in-between $\text{Re}\, f(k)<0$ $n$ times.
Does this seem reasonable?